# "Could not find the main class" in Java Salesforce application

Tags: java, eclipse, salesforce, classnotfoundexception

I've been building an application in Eclipse which extracts data from salesforce and using an imported CSV file, updates and inserts records.  It works fine from within Eclipse and I'm happy it's ready for deployment, but I cannot get the application working if I try and run it from cmd or double click the Jar.  I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: uploader/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: uploader.jar
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: uploader.jar.  Program will exit.
```

I've been all over google and tried every solution out there, but can't find why it won't work.  Here's the steps I'm using to build the jar and run it, please if anyone can show me where I'm going wrong, I'd be delighted!  I'm not a java programmer...

The project is called **uploader** as is the package, by the way

1. Right click on project and click Export.  Choose "Jar file" and
   Next.
2. Select my project as the resource and ensure .classpath and .project
   files are selected.  Choose to Export generated class files and
   resources, to Compress the contents of the JAR file, and choose the
   location for the Jar file to go, then hit Next.
3. Choose to Export class files with compile errors, and warnings. 
   Choose to Save the description of this JAR in the workspace, and
   give the location as /uploader/jardesc.jardesc.  Hit Next.
4. Choose to Generate the manifest file, Save the manifest in the
   workspace and Use the saved manifest in the generated JAR
   description file.
5. Point the Main Class to the correct place by clicking Browse and
   choosing the only option that I'm given, which is uploader.Main,
   then click Finish.

If I now open the manifest file, I see the following:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: uploader.Main
```

So that looks correct to me.

However, if I open a command prompt, cd to the directory containing the jar file then say java uploader.jar, that's when I get the error above.

Can anyone see anything that looks wrong?  I can't get past this point!

If I run with java -jar uploader.jar, I get this error instead:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sforce/ws/ConnectionException
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sforce.ws.ConnectionException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: uploader.Main. Program will exit.
```

Perhaps that can help pinpoint the problem?

****EDIT****

I've edited the manifest.mf file to this, but I'm still getting the error:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: uploader.Main
Class-Path: lib/enterprise.jar lib/wsc-22.jar
```

Comment: On the command line it would not be `java uploader.jar` but `java -jar uploader.jar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be a missing classpath setting, i.e. a definition of the classes and libraries that are needed in addtion. In your case it seems like at least some salesforce jar has to be added to the classpath.

Either put the classpath into the manifest file or add it at the command line: `java -cp <classpath here> -jar uploader.jar`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Thomas, please see my edited question for the response.

Comment: @StevenHayhurst well, the `.classpath` file is for Eclipse. Command line Java doesn't know this file even exists.

Comment: Didn't realise that, so thanks.  I've changed the manifest file but still getting the error.  Check the question for my file

Comment: @StevenHayhurst I assume the `lib` folder is right next to the `uploader.jar` and you're executing the commandline from the folder both are in, right? I further assume you are sure that the class in question is contained in those jars.

Comment: That's right.  The lib folder and uploader.jar are in the same "uploader" directory and if I open lib/wsc-22.jar in winRAR I can see that com/sforce/ws/ConnectionException.java does indeed exist.  I am cd-ing the commandline to that "uploader" directory and executing from there.  Thanks for the continued help @Thomas!

Comment: @StevenHayhurst your classpath entry looks fine and if you correctly rebuilt uploader.jar (you might want to clean your build first, i.e. delete the jar and all .class files) and execute it the class should be found. If not there's probably a subtle error somewhere else. One question though: could you try reversing the class path entries and put `lib/wsc-22.jar` in the first place? Maybe it's not loaded due to problems with `lib/enterprise.jar` - allthough you should get other errors as well in that case.

Comment: I've sorted it.  Using Eclipse I decided to try Exporting it as a Runnable Jar instead of just a Jar.  Did this and it works.  Don't really know what the difference is and why JAR wouldn't work but I'm happy now I've sorted it.  By opening the jar in winRAR I could see that it didn't seem to be building properly so thought I'd try runnable jar instead and it worked.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ministe2003 glad to hear it works now. To find the differences check the content of both jar versions, especially the manifest.